# Disable scroll effect when hovering on a specific button

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using Satelite theme for wordpress that has a built in scroll effect when you hover over buttons in the menu. Also I'm using Polylang for language support and so the problem is when you hover over the button in the menu it scrolls and reveals a bit of code instead of the language flag again.

Theme preview: http://clapat.ro/themes/satelite-wordpress/

Comment: check for any missing closing < or > symbols in your html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a solution for you, but there may be other ones. I don't know your theme, so I'll try to solve it in a more general way:

When I inspect the code of your theme, I can see that the effect is being done by using the ::before pseudo attribute in CSS:

In your HTML

```
<span data-hover="About">About</span>
```

In your CSS

```
.classic-menu .flexnav li a span::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    content: attr(data-hover);
}
```

As you can see, it takes the value of your "data-hover" attribute and adds it as value for the content attribute of `::after`.

It is possible to set an image as the content. But you have to use another syntax:

```
div::before {
  content: url(image.jpg);
}
```

So the solution would be to set an ID or class for your image menu items. With this ID, you can target them in your css and overwrite the CSS by hand:

```
#your_menu_item::before {
    content: url(yourimagepath.jpg);
}
```

You can also set a fallback, if the image is not working:

```
content: url(image.jpg) / "Your fallback text";
```

So you have to find out the path of your images and insert them to your css.

I think the theme author did not mean to put images in menu items, so I guess it simply outputs the image tag on hover. So you have to change the hover for your menu items.

I hope this helps!

EDIT: With your link I can see the markup, thanks your this. You've got to add to your style.css

```
#menu-item-500 li a span::before {
    content: url(data:image/png;base64,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) !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried applying it but it didn't work, I'm sorry in hind sight I wasn't very clear. Basically with normal buttons the site is displaying the name of the menu, for example "About us". So when I hover over, it scrolls, grabs the name again and display it normally. But the button I'm having issues with is the integration of the polylang plugin. Basically let's say the site is in English and I want to switch. It display the English flag normally and when I hover over instead of displaying the English flag once again, it seemingly grabs the URL and displays a snippet instead. Thank you so far.

Comment: Yes, it acts exactly like I described ;) I applied the code for your markup. You need to add this in your custom css.